# create github pull request from a jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, github, pull-request

I want to create a PR to my git repository from a jenkins pipeline.

I know it's a bit revers flow than the general flow where we trigger jenkins job based on PRs.
But in my case, user will manually trigger a job & I will create clone an existing git repo. After that, will update some files (via the same job pipeline). And then I want these changes to be pushed to my github repo & have a PR ready to be reviewed by the devs.

Is there any way to do this ? 
I am trying around [hub](https://hub.github.com) but want to know if there's any other way of achieving this?